# SQL Concat field from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I would like to create a function that returns a concatinated string of a given field of given query. Here is what I did.
And this one gives me an error.
**Must declare the table variable "@qry".**

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.testing 
    ( 
    @qry varchar(1000),
    @fld varchar(100),
    @separator varchar(15) = '; '
    )
RETURNS  varchar
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @rslt varchar(1000)
    SET @rslt ='' 

     SELECT @rslt = @rslt + @separator + CAST(@fld as varchar(160)) FROM  @qry

    RETURN @rslt
    END
```

What I am trying to do is pass a query to this function and receive a concatinated string for certain field of the query.

Is this possible?

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: BTW I have MSSQL Server 2005;

Comment: do it like: **Set @rslt=NULL; SELECT ISNULL(@rslt+@separator,'')+...** so you don't get a @separator at the start of the @rslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a FROM @variable.  You'd have to use dynamic SQL and make your @qry a derived table or something of that nature.  However, I think that's really not the best approach.  I believe this is what you're trying to do:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2007/10/02/t-sql-user-defined-function-to-concatenate-column-to-csv-string.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217202303/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mnf/archive/2007/10/02/t-sql-user-defined-function-to-concatenate-column-to-csv-string.aspx)

Make sure to read the comments on the XML alternative solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass through any form of dynamic SQL, you need to execute it via EXEC or (preferred) sp_ExecuteSQL. Make sure your code's not subject to any injection attacks if you're using dynamic SQL as well lest you suffer the wrath of [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) :-)